# Join two text() statements in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

What is the recommended way to join two text() statements in SQLAlchemy?

```
q1 = text('select a, b from table1')
q2 = text('select b, xxx from table2')
```

How do I join these two statements on column 'b', when none of them has the `c` (columns) attribute, so I cannot do `.outerjoin(q2, q1.c.b == q2.c.b)`. The final query I need is following:

```
SELECT a,b,xxx from table1 left join table2 on table1.b = table2.b;
```

What is the recommended way do it? What is easiest way to "fake" the columns in `c` ?

Note: I gave simple example with the text statements. In reality, they are much more complicated than this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`TextClause.columns()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.TextClause.columns) to [specify result columns](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/tutorial.html#using-textual-sql), which also turns your `text()` construct to a [`TextAsFrom`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.TextAsFrom) that has the usual features of a selectable:

```
# Replace with the actual types
q1 = text('select a, b from table1').columns(a=String, b=String)
q2 = text('select b, xxx from table2').columns(b=String, xxx=String)
```

You cannot transform the two statements to

```sql
SELECT a,b,xxx from table1 left join table2 on table1.b = table2.b
```

exactly, since SQLAlchemy is not an SQL parser, but you can produce an equivalent query by treating the two queries as subqueries and join them:

```
q1 = q1.alias()
q2 = q2.alias()

q = select([q1.c.a, q1.c.b, q2.c.xxx]).\
    select_from(q1.outerjoin(q2, q2.c.b == q1.c.b))
```